# Applying a UIImageView to only a specific section in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a simple application which is made up of a `UITabBar` where each `Tab` is a `UITableViewController`. For the purpose of this question, I will only focus on the `UITableViewController` called `Videos` (1st Tab) and another `UITableViewController` called `Languages` (2nd Tab).

The Vid`e`os Tab is made up of one section of a list of Videos. The `Languages` tab contains two sections, where `section 0` is Leaflets and `section 1` = the same corresponding Videos as the Videos tab.

So for example, if the `Videos` tab has:

- Video 10010
- Video 20010
- Video 30010
- Video 40010
- Video 50010

Then the `Languages` tab section 1 will also have:

- Video 10010
- Video 20010
- Video 30010
- Video 40010
- Video 50010

I have some code which puts a star on any cell that has been selected and the title of this cell is getting added to `Core Data` (to be displayed in the 3rd tab called `Favourites` - but this isn't important for this question).

I want to ensure consistency within the app, so if I place a star in `Video 20010` in the `Videos` tab, I want to make sure that the `Video 20010` in the Languages also has a star.

That part works. However, the **issue** is that the star gets placed in the Leaflets section (`section 0`) as well as the `Videos` section (`section 1`) of the `Languages` tab.

Here is part of the code of the `cellForRow` in the `Languages` tab.

```
// This code is important because I might set the Leaflets section to be a favourite from within the Languages tab (not related to the Videos tab, etc). 

if(indexPath.section==0)
{
    customCell.customCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.availableLeaflets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key]) {
        // show the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        // hide the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = YES;
    }
}
else
{
    customCell.customCellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(8, 20, 100, 40);
    customCell.customCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.availableVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key]) {
        // show the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        // hide the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = YES;
    }

}

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Favourites"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != nil"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *favs = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];    
if (!favs)
{
    NSLog(@"Nothing to see here");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Number of objects %lu", [favs count]);
    for (Favourites *favourite in favs)
    {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", favourite.title];
        favourite.title = string;
        NSLog(@"The favourite titles are %@", favourite.title);

        if ([customCell.customCellLabel.text isEqualToString:favourite.title])
        {

            customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**

When a cell is favourited, this is what's happening:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell *selectedCell = (CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *cellTitle = selectedCell.customCellLabel.text;

NSLog(@"The text is %@", cellTitle);

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil)
{
    self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1);
    Favourites *favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    favourites.title = cellTitle;

}
else
{

    [self.favoritesDict removeObjectForKey:key];
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext: context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", cellTitle];
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error == nil && items.count)
    {
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = items[0];
        [context deleteObject:managedObject];

    }
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.favoritesDict forKey:@"favoritesDict"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error])
{
    // Error
}

[cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

I am not interested in putting the image in the Leaflets section of the Languages tab (`section 0`); I just want to target the Videos section (`section 1`). With this code above, the correct cell in `section 1` is getting the UIImageView being applied, but I want to make sure the first section (Leaflets) is NOT getting the star as well.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's hard for me to follow what you're doing when someone favorites something. It looks like you're adding a dictionary to NSUserDefaults, but you are also getting a managed object, but you don't do anything with it. Are there leaflets with the same title as videos? If so, you should come up with a better way to structure your data.

Comment: Thanks @beyowulf - the Leaflets and Videos have different titles. I had the dictionary so that I can keep track of which row/which section has been favourited, so if I favourite something in the leaflets section, the videos section shouldn't have a favourite. The ManagedObjectContext is used simply to add the title of the favourited cell to Core Data. So the issue here is that in the cellForRow, I have it checking whether there's any favourites, and if there are, which row/which section.

Comment: The problem is that when I favourite a Video from the Videos tab, I want only the Videos section in the Languages to have a favourite and not the Leaflets. Everything relating to Favouriting items is working in the app; it's just this part and I guess I need to do something with the NSDictionary that stores the sections, etc.

Comment: In the Video tab, what section are the video's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after you dequeue the cell say `customCell.customCellImage.hidden = YES;` Then change:

```
if ([customCell.customCellLabel.text isEqualToString:favourite.title])
        {

            customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
        }
```

To:

```
if ([customCell.customCellLabel.text isEqualToString:favourite.title] && indexPath.section == 1)
        {

            customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @beyowulf - that's really helpful and that makes sense. I've just updated the question because I realise the big of the cellForRow I had omitted from the question was the key part here. I understand why now the section 0 is getting stared as well. The code I have updated the question with before the NSManagedObject is related to the fact that the user has the option to star either the Leaflet (section 0) or Video (section 1) in the Languages tab, or they might favourite JUST a video from the Video tab, so I'm not sure how to make my way around this.

Comment: With a big of testing and debugging, this does actually work. I was doing something over-complicated. Thanks very much for your help with this @beyowulf.

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you have the key part, which is the `indexPath`.  Add the following condition to your if statement.

```
indexPath.section == 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Avi - that makes sense and I've updated the question to include areas of why I think this is still failing.